# Magento contact form on CMS page shows 404 error

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I added my contact form.phtml to a cms page with the following code:

`{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}`

However when I submit the contact form it will show a 404 error because the URL is being routed to www.domain.de/contacts/index/post, which doesn't exist because I use URL rewrites with store codes (de/en).

So the routing should go to www.domain.de/de/contacts/index/post

This only works when I alter the code as follows:

`{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="http://domain.de/de/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}`

Since I am pretty new to magento I didn't find a solution  and I dont know if this could be a problem with the .htaccess file.

Did anyone have the same issue and knows how to fix it?

Update:

Just to make sure if I did it correctly:
I created `\app\code\local\MARG\ContactForm\etc\config.xml\` with the following content:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MARG_ContactForm>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MARG_ContactForm>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <ContactForm>
                <class>MARG_ContactForm_Block</class>
            </ContactForm>
        <blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then I created `app\code\local\MARG\ContactForm\Block\ContactForm.php` with content:

```
class MARG_ContactForm_Block_ContactForm extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
   protected function_construct()
   {
       $this ->setTemplate('contacts/form.phtml');
       parent::_construct();
   }

    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return Mage::getUrl('*/*/post', array('_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()));
    }
}
```

In `app\etc\modules\MARG_ContactForm.xml`I put content:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MARG_ContactForm>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MARG_ContactForm>
    </modules>
</config>
```

In the CMS page I added `{{block type="MARG/ContactForm" name="contactForm"}}`

Is there something i overlooked?

Edit:

i have done it exactly as described and added `{{block type="ContactForm/ContactForm" name="contactForm"}}` to the CMS page. However it still shows a blank page the exception.log says

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_ContactForm_Block_ContactForm' in C:\dev\plain\magento\app\Mage.php:595 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\dev\plain\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...') 
#1 C:\dev\plain\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('ContactForm/Con...', Array)
```

Comment: The exception suggests that Magento is not resolving "ContactForm" to the a class name.  Disable the caches in "System > Cache Management".  If that does not help try changing the `<ContactForm>` tag to lowercase and the block type in your CMS page to the equivalent. Play around with it to get a feel.

Comment: I have tried both ways, they don't work. have u gotten this to work in your local magento system? i wonder if i really have to give up on this

Comment: I tried copy-pasting what you have so far and needed to fix these;  In config.xml the closing blocks tag should be `</blocks>`.  In ContactForm.php there needs to be a space after "function".  Neither typo caused the error message you are seeing.

Comment: did these changes result in showing the form in the cms page? because in mine it still wont show it

Comment: It did.  All I can suggest is to look at your typing very carefully, just in case you made a beginner's mistake.

Comment: I have found a typo in it, now I have managed to see the form inserted in the CMS page. However, as soon as I click submit, the requested URL is `http://my-domain.com/de/cms/page/post/` which is not a valid URL. 404 page is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the block is type `Mage_Core_Block_Template` which doesn't have a function to turn form action into a fully qualified URL.  Normally that happens in `Mage_Contacts_IndexController` but of course your CMS page is not using that controller.

The solution is to make a block type which suits your purpose.  I'll assume you know how to make a module and that it's name is "example".

```
class Example_Example_Block_Contacts extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('contacts/form.phtml');
        parent::_construct();
    }

    public function getFormAction()
    {
        // copied from Mage_Contacts_IndexController::indexAction()
        return Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post', array('_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()));
    }
}
```

This makes your CMS page simpler too.  It only needs to include:

```
{{block type="example/contacts" name="contactForm"}}
```

Comment: i have created a module now, but where do i have to put the upper code which you have posted? sorry im creating a module for the first time

Comment: I have done the following:
I created a model, and added Modulename/ContactForm/Block/ContactForm.php with your above posted content (amended the Example_Example_Block_Contacts to ..._Block_ContactForm) and tried to put it into my cms page like that:
`{{block type="Modulename/contactform" name="contactForm"}}`
but it doesn't show the form on my CMS page

Comment: If you haven't done so already turn on logging in "System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings" then watch the "var/log" directory for possible clues.

Comment: do you know if theres something i can do? i added info to the initial question

Comment: I just realised `getFormAction` was returning the wrong URL.